# Search like sql using '%' criteria native sql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a code to connect *PL/SQL* search like using '%' and I use criteria to implement

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());

if(searchCharacterInfo.getKeyword() != null){
      sql += " WHERE NAME LIKE %:keyword% ";
      query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql).setParameter("keyword", keyword);
}

List<Object> res =  query.getResultList();
return res;
```

When I run this code to show error:

```
Could not locate named parameter keyword
```

Please help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter placeholder isn't just blindly replaced with the placeholder value, so `%:keyword%` is not a legal syntax.

You need to have `LIKE :keyword` in SQL, and pass keyword as `"%" + keyword + "%"` from the Java side.

Alternately, you could concatenate strings on the SQL side: `LIKE ('%' || :keyword || '%')`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a model class EMPLOYEE. so you can write criteria as follows :

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<EMPLOYEE> cq = cb.createQuery(EMPLOYEE.class);
        Root<EMPLOYEE> employee = cq.from(EMPLOYEE.class);
        cq.select(employee);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (searchCharacterInfo.getKeyword() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(employee.get("name"), "%" + searchCharacterInfo.getKeyword() + "%"));
        }
    
        cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        List<EMPLOYEE> res =  entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```